# Strip multiple filenames of leading numbers and spaces

Tags: bash, scripting

In bash. So that `001 file.ext` becomes `file.ext`. How would I do that?

Comment: So, is it a mistype that you have two i's in 'file'?  I.e. do you actually want it to convert from 001 fiile.ext to file.ext or do you want it to convert 001 file.ext to file.ext?

Answer (score 1):

You can use two seds expressions. The first one removes everything upto the last space, and the second strips off leading digits.

```
$ echo "001 fiile.ext" | sed -e 's/^.* //' -e 's/^[0-9]*//g'
fiile.ext
```

Comment: This might not meet the poster's needs - e.g., if there are spaces remaining in the filename after leading numbers and spaces are removed.  This can be fixed with a slight tweak to your sed expression:    echo "001 fiile.ext" | sed -e 's/^[ 0-9]*//'

Answer (score 1):

```
for f in *file.ext
do
    newname=$(echo "$f" | sed 's/^[0-9 ]*//')
    mv "$f" "$newname"
done
```

Or in pure Bash:

```
shopt -s extglob
for f in *file.ext
do
    mv "$f" "${f##+([0-9 ])}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to convert filenames (as vars in a script), you can just do something like:

```
[[ $FILENAME =~ ^[0-9\s]+(.+) ]] && FILENAME="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

If you're trying to actually rename filenames on the filesystem, something like this is more appropriate

```
for F in *.ext; do
  [[ $F =~ ^[0-9\s]+(.+) ]] && mv "$F" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
done
```